# Angular Material: Layout Containers to fill parent

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angularjs 1.5 with Angular Material 1.0.5 to create a mock table. The issue I have is I can't get the child component 'cell' background-color to fill out 100% in height of the parent. Here is my jsfiddle. Any help on how to do this is appreciated?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/xt7bjq95/)

[image: Table]

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <style>
  .table-row{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  .table-cell{
    border-right:1px solid black;
  }
  </style>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/table">
  <div layout='column'>
    <div ng-repeat='col in [0,1,2]'>
      <div layout="row" class='table-row'>
        <div layout-align='center center' ng-repeat='row in [0,1,2]' flex class='table-cell'>
          <div ng-if='$odd' flex>
            <cell></cell>
          </div>
          <div ng-if='$even'flex>
            TEST</br>
            TEST</br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>

  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/cell">
    <div style='background-color:red'>
     CELL
    </div>
  </script>


  <h3>
  {{name}}
  </h3>

  <table>
  </table>

</div><!--end app-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a hierarchy of `layout="column/row" attributes. They are the containers for`flex`, otherwise your flex won't have any effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/t8pssapu/

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I thought it was to do with the use of component being issue, clearly not. Much appreciated!